# Excel Vba - Compilation Error - Variable Not Defined

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having difficulty using two codes in a worksheet for similar functions, when trying to use these two functions, the following message appears: variable not defined.

Could you help me on how to match the two codes below, please?

CODE 1:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    
    
    Dim celula As Range
    Dim intervalo As Range
    
 
    Set intervalo = Range("B9:B12; B15:B18; B20:B23; B25; B27:B28; B33; B36:B42; B52; A91; B91; C91; D91")



    For Each celula In intervalo
    
        If IsEmpty(celula.Value) Then
            MsgBox "A célula " & celula.Address & " está vazia, favor preencher."
            celula.Interior.Color = vbRed 'adicionar uma cor na celula
            Cancel = True
            
        Else
            celula.Interior.Color = xlNone
            
            
        End If
    
    Next
    

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim celula As Range
    Dim intervalo As Range
    
 
    Set intervalo = Range("B9:B12; B15:B18; B20:B23; B25; B27:B28; B33; B36:B42; B52; A91:A94; B91:B94; C91:C94; D91;D94")



    For Each celula In intervalo
    
        If IsEmpty(celula.Value) Then
            MsgBox "A célula " & celula.Address & " está vazia, favor preencher."
            celula.Interior.Color = vbRed 'adicionar uma cor na celula
            Cancel = True
            
        Else
            celula.Interior.Color = xlNone
        End If
    
    Next

End Sub
```

CODE 2:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)

qtdvazias = WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Range("B9:B11")) + WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Range("B15:B18"))

If qtdvazias >= 1 Then

MsgBox ("Campos obrigatórios vazios. Favor preencher")
Cancel = True
End If

End Sub
```

Code 1 was used so that the person who did not fill in the aforementioned cells would not be able to save the document or close it, and the cells that were missing would appear.

Code 2 is used so that the document is not printed if the cells mentioned are empty.

I believe there would be some code to match both cases. But I'm new to VBA.

Comment: Where are you defining what `qtdvazias` is? Looks to me like you forgot to `Dim` it, just like the error says.

Answer (score 2):

In Code 2 `qtdvaziasias` is not defined, hence the error message.  You need to start with:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
Dim qtdvaziasias as Integer
```

For the repeated code, you can extract it into a separate `Function` like this:

```
Private Function RequiredCellsMissing() As Boolean

Dim missing As Boolean
    
    missing = False

    Dim celula As Range
    Dim intervalo As Range
    
    Set intervalo = Range("B9:B12; B15:B18; B20:B23; B25; B27:B28; B33; B36:B42; B52; A91:A94; B91:B94; C91:C94; D91; D94")

    For Each celula In intervalo
    
        If IsEmpty(celula.Value) Then
            MsgBox "A célula " & celula.Address & " está vazia, favor preencher."
            celula.Interior.Color = vbRed 'adicionar uma cor na celula
            missing = True
        Else
            celula.Interior.Color = xlNone
        End If
    
    Next

    RequiredCellsMissing = missing

End Function
```

You then alter the existing code simply to:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    
    Cancel = RequiredCellsMissing()

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    Cancel = RequiredCellsMissing()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't get "Variable not defined" when I paste your code into a workbook. But I do get an "Application-defined or object-defined error" everywhere you have used

```
Set intervalo = Range("B9:B12; B15:B18; B20:B23; B25; B27:B28; B33; B36:B42; B52; A91:A94; B91:B94; C91:C94; D91;D94")
```

That is because the separator for a range like that is not a semi-colon - it's a comma e.g.

```
Range("B9:B12,B15:B18,B20:B23,B25,B27:B28,B33,B36:B42,B52,A91:A94,B91:B94,C91:C94,D91,D94")
```

Comment: Localization changes the delimiter in a range. You will get the Variable not Defined error if you turn on option explicit.